# Ordering entries in a Flutter SQFLITE database by multiple criteria/columns

Tags: flutter, sql-order-by, sqflite

I have created a flutter SQFlite database that works almost perfectly, allowing me to create new entries, view current entries or even delete entries. However, there is one things I can't seem to get right and that's ordering the entries.

Essentially, what I am after is for the newest item to be at the top. Each item has date and time data. The date data is stored in a format that looks like this:

```
Mon, 29/11/2021
```

The time data is stored in a format that looks like this:

```
08:53:48
```

I have basically written a function to read the entries from the database (to view in a ListView.builder widget) and whilst reading those entries, it orders them based on two criteria. The future function is like this:

```
  /// Function to read all database entries
  Future<List<Result>> readAllNotes() async {
    final db = await instance.database;
    final orderBy =
        '${ResultFields.date} DESC, ${ResultFields.time} DESC';
    final result = await db.query(Results, orderBy: orderBy);
    return result.map((json) => Result.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }
```

Now, according to this information I found:

https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-order-by/

I should be able to order by two separate columns. Whilst ordering by time is working fine, ordering by date is not. What's the reason for this? Why do the entries still display in a random order? For example, if I do one on Saturday, then Sunday, the Sunday one appears top. If I then do one on a Monday, the Monday one goes straight to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

So as it turns out, they were being put in alphabetical order, since the sqflite package couldn't recognise them as days of the week, so to speak (Sun, Sat, Mon are in the correct reverse alphabetical order).

In the end, the solution was to change the way the date was stored, so that it would always be shown in the correct date order. Therefore,

```
Mon, 29/11/2021
```

became

```
2021/11/29, Mon
```

This resolved the issue for me. I hope this helps someone else in a similar situation!